# Checking current python log time format

Tags: python

I am setting the python logger format by calling function

```
  30         logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
  31                             format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
```

For some unknown reason, python is not picking up the specified log time format and I want to check what is currently being used.

Does python logger provides anyway we can check what is the current time format being used at run time? Is there any python API do do this check?